How to improve call performance in a dynamic route in Next.js 14 with caching and revalidate?
I'm working with Next.js 14 and have a dynamic route with more than 10,000 products. The API calls made when a product is clicked and page load (found via a search bar) are slow. Unfortunately, I cannot optimize or speed up these calls. However, the data changes at most once a day after midnight.
I was wondering if there is a way to:
Pre-load all the information after midnight (even if it might be inefficient since only 10 products might be viewed throughout the day)
Pre-load all the information on the first user click and then cache it for the entire day
I have read the documentation on caching, revalidate, and revalidatePath, but I am not sure if these functionalities can help in my case.
Can someone provide guidance on how to implement a suitable solution?
Thanks in advance!

Is the API request what's slowing down your project? Does the server you consume your data from support pagination? Is it the image loading what feels slow? There's multiple things you could do depending on exactly what's slowing down your application.

One, you could check fetch with revalidate to have your requests cached in the server for subsequent requests to use. Two, if the images are the issue, you could try to cache them with a CDN to speed up their loading. Three, if the server does not have any sort of pagination (10k items is a lot for a single request), you could use a cache like Redis in front so your Next.js server consumes the data from a cache instead of directly from the API server.
